# Проверить домен перед покупкой на санкции со стороны ПС Яндекс и Гугл

Tags: seo

Яндекс накладывает на домен (или сайт?) пессимизирующие фильтры. В я.вебмастере такое можно наблюдать во вкладке "диагностика". Обычно сайт там помечается как "Фатальные. Обнаружены нарушения или проблемы с безопасностью".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вопрос: возможно ли перед покупкой домена проверить, не наложены для на домен фильтры?

Comment: Написать продавану чтобы дал гостевой доступ к Яндекс Метрике, не?

Comment: не, слишком муторно) да и покупать приходится в том числе и свободные домены

Comment: голосую за закрытие, так как другим способом не проверить, а дать объективный ответ нельзя